# Remove empty string , empty Arrays from response in MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework, aggregate

1. I have implement aggregate with MongoDB
2. want to remove null, empty string and empty array from response with nested array and object.
3. here is the sample response.

```
retVal = await DSModel.aggregate(input); // using aggregate to get data from DB

[
  {
    display_name: 'test name 1',
    contact_info: {
      registrar_phone: null, // remove null attribute from response
      registrar_email: null,
      addresses: [
        {
          addr2: null, // remove null attribute from nested array
          zipcode: '7102',
        },
      ],
    },
    score: 1.812557339668274,
  },
  {
    display_name: 'test name 2',
    contact_info: {
      registrar_phone: null, // remove null attribute from response
      registrar_email: null,
      addresses: [
        {
          addr2: null, // remove null attribute from nested array
          zipcode: '7103',
        },
      ],
    },
    score: 1.812557339668275,
  },
];
```

> how can i remove all null, empty string and empty array from response at nested level??
> i am using aggregate for get the value

Comment: @Ipizzinidev do you have any idea to remove null attributes from response ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$ifNull` with `$$REMOVE` for fields and `$filter` for arrays:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $set: {
      "contact_info.registrar_phone": {
        $ifNull: ["$contact_info.registrar_phone", "$$REMOVE"]
      },
      "contact_info.registrar_email": {
        $ifNull: ["$contact_info.registrar_email", "$$REMOVE"]
      },
      "contact_info.addresses": {
        $filter: {
          input: "$contact_info.addresses",
          as: "item",
          cond: {$ifNull: ["$$item.addr2", "$$REMOVE"]}
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $set: {
      "contact_info.addresses": {
        $cond: [
          {$eq: [{$size: "$contact_info.addresses"}, 0]},
          "$$REMOVE",
          "$contact_info.addresses"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/kOk0oFmuXd4)

Comment: i want this for whole schema, not for specific fields, so do i have any common way where i dont need to define KEY ??